# Связанный-связанные

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Что это за два списка в колонке справа и чем они отличаются? Замечено [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435475/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8c%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5).

[image: Связанный-связанные]

**Обновление**

Сейчас так:

```
Linked = Связанный
Related = Связанные
```

Выберите, пожалуйста, (как минимум) по одному подходящему варианту перевода для `Linked` и для `Related`.

Смысловая разница между ними объясняется в [этом ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/768/178576).

Comment: Применил следующий вариант: «Связанные», «Похожие». (до сегодняшнего дня было «Связанный»). Предлагаю принять ответ VladD.

Answer (score 10):

**Обновление:** Пожалуйста, голосуйте за варианты перевода в других ответах!

---

Спасибо за вопрос! Это проблема с переводом.

Верхний блок на английском SO назван Linked: там помещаются (насколько я понимаю) вопросы, на которые есть ссылки в обсуждении. Нижний блок — Related: вопросы, которые, по мнению системы, имеют отношение к данной теме.

Имеет смысл подправить перевод, чтобы смысл был более понятен.

---

Для голосования, предлагаю вариант:

```
Linked = Связанные
Related = Похожие
```

Comment: Мне не очень нравится перевод "Linked" как "Связанные": "link" - это "ссылка", соответственно, как мне кажется, должно быть однокоренное слово со словом "ссылка". На ум, правда, ничего не приходит.

Comment: @n0rd: Подождём, может кто-то подгонит ещё варианты.

Comment: "Связанные" хороший вариант.

Comment: «упомянутые», «затронутые», «касающиеся»

Comment: Коллеги, добавляйте варианты для голосования!

Comment: "Linked" здесь - вопросы, на которые есть прямая ссылка откуда-то со страницы с вопросом, или из комментариев, или из тела вопроса, или из ответа. Поэтому для "Linked" правильно оставить "связанные", хотя точнее было бы "ссылаемые", но такого слова нет, а если и есть, то ссылка в этом слове ведет на Магадан, а не на ресурс в Интернете. Можно развернуть, вроде "Вопросы, на которые ссылается этот", но уж очень неудобно. Так что лучше имеющийся вариант поддержу.

Comment: @n0rd, а еще "*link*" это "*связь*". т.о. "*linked*" - "*связанные*".

Comment: @Vesper: связь двухсторонняя: Linked—это список вопросов linked from/to. То есть если другой вопрос (в самом вопросе, ответах, комментариях) ссылается на текущий вопрос, ответ (и комментарий?), то он также попадает в этот список

Comment: Еще в этом списке появляются дубли.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: дубликаты не являются специальным случаем. В дубликате есть ссылка на оригинал, поэтому он добавляется по общему правилу: наличию ссылки между вопросами.

Comment: @VladD: разногласий с переводом "related" нет. Можете ли Вы поправить [перевод на transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265231)

Comment: @jfs: Сделал. (Раньше не мог, был в отпуске.)

Comment: @VladD: спасибо. [Оказалось, что не достаточно transifex обновить.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/385/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%81-transifex-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82#comment2648_385)

Comment: @jfs: Точно! Я помнил об этом раньше. Но забыл в отпуске :)

Comment: Применил ваш вариант. И знак получите )

Answer (score 4):

**вариант**

```
Related = Похожие
```

Answer (score 4):

**вариант**

```
Linked = Связанные
```

Answer (score 3):

linked - Упомянуто в обсуждении...
related - Также по теме...

Comment: linked question не обязан быть упомянут. Он может просто ссылаться на текущий вопрос. Список содержит linked from/to вопросы

Comment: @jfs ага, поправил на "упомянуто в обсуждении", можно трактовать и как from и как to

Answer (score 2):

**вариант**

```
Linked = Упомянутые
```

Comment: Тоже неплохой вариант, даже более понятный на мой взгляд.

Comment: Не все linked questions могут быть упомянуты на странице. Часть вопросов из списка могут сами ссылаться на текущий вопрос, то есть связь двухсторонняя (linked to/from)

Answer (score 1):

**вариант**

```
Linked = Затронутые
```

Answer (score 0):

**вариант**

```
Related = Схожие
```

Answer (score -1):

**вариант**

```
Related = Связанные
```

Answer (score -2):

**вариант**

```
Linked = Касающиеся
```